How can I get the dependencies of centos google-chrome-stable when I have a Debian machine?
I am working on Debian but am using a Docker image using yum (hence why I think Centos), specifically FROM amazoncorretto:17.0.11-al2). I need to get the dependencies of google-chrome-stable and I can ssh into the Docker without issue. Does anyone know how I can do so?

I was able to get it working with the following. There were two main issues:

I thought I was using al2023 (Amazon Linux 2023) but I was using AL2
I needed to add some more dependencies

ARG CHROME_VERSION=129.0
# Stage 1: Pre-built Selenium Standalone Chrome image
FROM selenium/standalone-chrome:${CHROME_VERSION} as chrome

FROM amazoncorretto:17.0.12-al2023
RUN yum install -y libX11 libXcomposite libXcursor libXdamage libXext libXi libXtst cups-libs libXScrnSaver libXrandr alsa-lib pango atk at-spi2-atk gtk3 nss cups wget libdrm mesa-libgbm

# Copy Chrome and ChromeDriver from the first stage
COPY --from=chrome /usr/bin/chromedriver /usr/bin/chromedriver
COPY --from=chrome /opt/google/chrome/ /opt/google/chrome/

# Set environment variables for Chrome and ChromeDriver
ENV CHROME_BIN=/opt/google/chrome/google-chrome
ENV CHROMEDRIVER_BIN=/usr/bin/chromedriver

# In the original consulting file CHROMEDRIVER_PORT, CHROMEDRIVER_WHITELISTED_IPS, and CHROMEDRIVER_URL_BASE are not set
ENV CHROMEDRIVER_PORT 4444
ENV CHROMEDRIVER_WHITELISTED_IPS "127.0.0.1"
ENV CHROMEDRIVER_URL_BASE ''

# App Setup
EXPOSE 8080

# Copy application JAR into the image
ARG JAR_FILE=target/*.jar
COPY ${JAR_FILE} app.jar

ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar", "-Xmx600m", "/app.jar"]

